# Argument passed to __construct() must be an instance of \Helper\Data

Tags: construct

I get this error
Argument 2 passed to [VENDOR][MODULE]\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an instance of [VENDOR][MODULE]\Helper\Data

this is my controller

```
namespace [VENDOR]\[MODULE]\Controller\Index;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use \[VENDOR]\[MODULE]\Helper\Data;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $helperData;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     *
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Data $helperData,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory

    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context
        );
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->helperData = $helperData;
    }

    /**
     * Prints the blog from informed order id
     * @return Page
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo $this->helperData->getGeneralConfig('enable');
        echo $this->helperData->getGeneralConfig('display_text');
        exit();
        // $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        // return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

this is my helper

```
namespace [VENDOR]\[MODULE]\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    const XML_PATH_BLOG = 'blog/';

    public function getConfigValue($field, $storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $field, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId
        );
    }

    public function getGeneralConfig($code, $storeId = null)
    {

        return $this->getConfigValue(self::XML_PATH_BLOG .'general/'. $code, $storeId);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whenever you make some changes on dependency injection, you just have to run from your Magento root directory following command:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

This will compile the Dependency Injection (DI) again and, your issue will go away.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/170380/28451

Comment: You don't need to this every time. You can just instead delete var/generation, var/di

Comment: I tried but it did not work

Comment: What version of magento do you have?

Comment: Magento ver. 2.2.3

Comment: The di stuff is under /generated